# Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k b_{nk}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_kc_k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

Let $\{a_k\}$ be a sequence of non negative real numbers such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k =1$. Let $b_{nk}$ is a double array sequence of real numbers where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.It is given that $0 \le b_{nk} \le M$ uniformly. Suppose $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_{nk}=c_k $ for all $k$.Prove that
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k b_{nk}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_kc_k$

Now, I approached this by looking at the difference $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k b_{nk} - a_k c_k=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k (b_{nk}-c_k)$.

As we know that $|b_{nk}-c_k|< \epsilon$ for $n > N_{k}$. I take the supremum of all such $N_k$'s to be $N$. So, if now $n>N$, the difference must go to $0$ right? But how can I guarantee the existence of the supremum? Also, how can I use the boundedness of $b_{nk}$?

Comment: why not first evaluate the partial sum $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^Ka_kb_{nk}$?

Comment: Okay, can you elaborate, how that can help?

Comment: oh sorry, let $d_K = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{K} a_kb_{nk}$, by a theorem about the sum of (a finite number of) limits, $d_K =  \sum_{k=1}^{K}\lim_{n\to \infty}a_kb_{nk} = \sum_{k=1}^{K}a_kc_k$ I'm not immediately sure you can conclude $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  a_kb_{nk}= \lim_{K\to\infty}d_K$, but seems reasonable...

Comment: Looks like an application of [Tannery's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem) validates my method, might be worth a double checking though.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Given $\epsilon >0$ choose $N$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty} a_k <\epsilon$. Note that $|\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty} [a_kb_{nk} -a_kc_k]| \leq 2M\epsilon$ since the hypothesis implies that $|c_k| \leq M$ for all $k$ which gives $|b_{nk}-c_k| \leq 2M$. Next note that $|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} [a_kb_{nk} -a_kc_k]| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. I will let you finish the proof.

Comment: So,suppose I define $S_k=a_k b_{nk} - a_{k}c_{k}$. You proved that $|\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}S_k| < 2M \epsilon$ this just implies that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} S_k $ is finite right? Or does it imply something else?

Comment: @MathsFreak You want to show that $\sum S_k \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$. Split this as sum from $k=1$ to $k=N$ and the sum from $k=N+1$ to $\infty$. Choose $m$ such that the first sum is less than $\epsilon $(in absolute value) for all $n>m$. Then you get $|s_k| <\epsilon (2M+1)$ for $n >m$.